# Java - Running .jar heapdump error

Tags: java, memory, jvm, server

I'm running a .jar on an IBM i (AS400) Server. Everything works fine, my .jar runs a TCP server using Netty Framework for sockets. After a while, Java throws heap dump error and stops execution. It generates files: .phd and .txt.

How can I solve this? Why is this produced?

Comment: Cause of the problem may be in the core dump generated.

Comment: I'm getting Exception: OutOfMemory

Comment: Share generated exception please.